# Как указать номер строки в sql(python)?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

Такая ситуация: необходимо вывести определённую строку в python из базы данных SQL, состоящую из двух столбцов (сразу два значения). Как лучше всего это реализовать?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() в CTE. Если нужен не номер, а только сама строка - ORDER BY и LIMIT.

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то никакого порядка строк в таблице нет, так что про номер строки говорить нельзя. Номер строки имеет смысл только когда явно задан порядок например конструкцией ORDER BY